# Photoshop CS6 -> Export Layers To Files Subfolders

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, export, batch-processing

I hope that anybody of you could be able to solve my Problem.

I'm using **Photoshop CS6** and would like to get only the filename prefix I specify. If I try using the `Export Layers to Files` command, I get the prefix I created, like '**S03_**', but then there is another prefix automatically added like **'0001'**.

Also, if I have the layers in a group, the prefix is kind of like **'0001s'** and then there is another one like **'0001'**.

I searched and found out how to solve that first prefix problem '0001'. So now I'm left with the second problem. I think that it is because these layers are in a group and so the name of the file is now **'S03_0000s_example.png'**.

I would like to have these **'0000s'** prefix gone, or it should be replaced by the name of the Folder it is in like **'S03_examplefolder_example.png'**

Comment: Have you tried any batch renaming software? It might be easier than trying to change how Photoshop works.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop CC just added the [Generate](http://blogs.adobe.com/samartha/2013/09/a-closer-look-at-the-photoshop-generator-syntax.html) feature which would allow you to dynamically export layers. that combined with [Layrs](http://madebyvadim.com/layrs/) is pretty awesome. but this won't help you in CS6, sorry.

the easiest workaround would be batch rename in bridge, that will allow you the control over the renaming you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Photoshop itself that affords that level of fine control. The workaround is to use the Batch Rename feature in Adobe Bridge or Image Processor Pro (which comes as part of [Dr Brown's Services](https://www.adobeexchange.com/store/products/315#.UzZla_8e6wI)), or to use an external batch renaming utility.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, they are adding the second modifier because there are groups; have you tried working in slices and saving that way instead? You'd get just the single name. Well you'd get a lot more flexibility all the way around, anyway.

You could look up how to batch rename via command prompt, if it's not too scary. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

There is also an improved version of the `Export Layers to Files` that skips the "0000" prefix.

https://github.com/jwa107/Photoshop-Export-Layers-to-Files-Fast